# Unable to read branch name

Tags: jenkins, groovy, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Read this [readme](https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin/blob/master/README.md)

Installed GitLab plugin in Jenkins

Below script is able to read correct repository name but wrong branch name

```
node('worker_node'){

    stage('stage1'){

        def repoName = env.gitlabSourceRepoName
        println "Repository Name: " + repoName

        def repoUrl = env.gitlabSourceRepoURL
        println "Repository url: " + repoUrl


        def repoSshUrl = env.gitlabSourceRepoSshUrl
        println "Repository ssh url: " + repoSshUrl


        def repoHttpUrl = env.gitlabSourceRepoHttpUrl
        println "Repository http url: " + repoHttpUrl

        def branchName = env.gitlabSourceBranch
        println "Branch name: " + branchName
   }
}
```

---

## Edit:

Below are the setting on GitLab:

[image]

---

I have webhook with multiple branches in a GitLab repository.

On webhook, Why `branchName` always give `master`?

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation in https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin#webhook-url you should use:

> "For single-repository workflows: origin/${gitlabSourceBranch}"
>
> "For forked repository workflows: merge-requests/${gitlabMergeRequestIid}"

Comment: @overexchange please post your webhook settings.

Comment: @Nick Added webhook settings in Query

Comment: @overexchange The documentation of the jenkins gitlab plugin states that you use this url format `http://USERID:APITOKEN@JENKINS_URL/project/YOUR_JOB` and you enter nothing in the secret field, more info [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin#gitlab-to-jenkins-authentication).

Comment: @Nick But the webhook works, in any case, if I clieck the Test button on that webhook. How this is related to issue of not able to read branchname?

Comment: How do you test and always get master? You need to open a PR to use `env.gitlabSourceBranch` if you just push to one branch use `env.gitlabBranch`. Also if your job is a  Pipeline Multibranch, these vars won't work as stated in the docs.